# Mac: inconsistent boot problems

Tags: macos, mac, boot, osx-mountain-lion, mac-pro

I have been having some serious issues with my Mac Pro recently, and my business has been brought to a standstill.

First my specs: Mac Pro 3,1 quad 2.8, 14GB RAM, ATI Radeon 2600 (stock), ATI Radeon HD3870, original 320GB system drive of which 115GB is free.

The symptoms: Yesterday, starting up in the morning in the middle of a large project, my Mac would not boot. It hung at the white Apple logo screen. Forced a shut down, ran applejack, ran fsck, booted into safe mode and ran Onyx. It locked up half way through the volume structure test. Forced another shut down, sweating because a deadline was looming, and tried a number of other things, resetting SMC (unplugging power cable method), resting NVRAM, booted into Recovery Drive and repaired permissions, ran Onyx again successfully this time. During all this there were times where the second monitor went all weird, which initially made me think the video card could be the culprit. Disconnected two monitors from the 3870 and hooked one up to the 2600. Booted up fine and Was able to work in Illustrator for the rest of the day. Shut down at day's end thinking nothing of it.

Booted up this morning, same routine. Although this time it took forever to even get to a working system. Nothing I tried worked, it kept hanging up at the white logo screen. Eventually got to boot into safe mode and tried Onyx, which hung at the same point again. So I'm thinking hard drive failing. It's old, over five years by a long way. But every drive test or SMART test has not shown signs of failing. Was considering recovering the system from Time Machine using Recovery Drive, but needed to be sure before going all the way down that path. Figured it might be RAM but the Power On System Test passed. I tried to run the Apple Hardware Test, but despite hours of trying every conceivable combination suggested I could not get it to run.

I ran TechToolPro from its eDrive partition and all drives passed all tests, as did memory, etc, etc. Currently I'm cloning my boot drive ready for a clean install. After some reading I found references to possible failing power supply. I don't think this is likely as when I boot into Recovery Mode, or the eDrive, everything runs smoothly. This makes me believe it's a software issue on my main boot drive.

So, before I jump down a particular foxhole, what's the opinion on the most likely culprit: RAM, hard drive, malware, video card. I haven't had an anti virus program since Norton on OS9. Are they worthwhile? Any recommendations?

Sorry for the massive post. Tried to share as much detail. I value and appreciate any info shared.

Adam

Comment: The overall/summary "SMART status: Verified" is useless, but the error counters you can read via SMART are useful. Run Disk Utility, select your boot volume (the volume, not the hard drive itself) and choose `File > Get Info`. It should show you the SMART counters. If the Pending, Removed, or Reallocated bad sector counters are not all zero, then your drive is dying.

Comment: Thanks Spiff. I also used TechToolPro which did a much more thorough job of inspecting the blocks and sectors on the drive. Nothing was flagged. I agree with SMART, it's never been much use to me either, but TTP has been accurate enough for me to trust it in the past. Anyhow I'm ordering a Samsung EVO 850 to drop in. Done. Moving forward.

Comment: I'd still be curious to know what Disk Utility reports for those counters I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to rapidly separate possible causes:  either hardware or software.

1. do you have a separate boot drive or bootable thumbdrive available?? If so, boot from it (hold option when you power-on, and it'll bring up the bootloader to give you the choice of available drives for booting)..
   if you can boot from a known-good boot drive, then you know the issue is either your original hard drive (and please tell us you've got a good timemachine back up of your drive, considering that you're running your computer on a hard drive built in 2006, and has the equivalence of 600,000 miles on it!!).
2. if i had to guess, my initial guess would be that you have  a bad/dying hard drive, causing issues.   frankly, I wouldn't do a thing before a bought a SSD drive and an adaptor on amazon, installed them in one the bays, and reinstalled a fresh OS on it.. that's the first step.
3. if you've been able to get it up on ANY drive to look at data on the unit, run anything more than 3 or 4 minutes, then it's VERY unlikely to be the power supply.
4. highly unlikely the RAM.. you might take the door off, and look at the ram slots while running-there are some error lights on the cards - you'll see them if they're on... (don't pull cards out while it's running)

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks. Yes I know I'm playing with fire with a drive so old and that was my initial reaction too. I do have time machine back ups of important stuff, but not the system so not I can't reinstall from it. I do have a clone of the system drive and I can boot just fine from it. Strange though, the system boot drive has passed every single test I threw at it. No failing drive indications. Is this possible/typical? If so what's the point of diagnosis software or SMART? Good news about the power supply. Those are expensive.

Comment: SMART is basically useless as a diagnostics tool, for a number of reasons.  IF a cloned backup is working, then you need to get a good SSD drive in a sled, duplicate for it, and move forward..